# computing a correlation for every type of event

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function journalEvents(journal) {
let events = [];
for (let entry of journal) {
  for (let event of entry.events) {
    if (!events.includes(event)) {
      events.push(event);
  }
 }
}
return events;
}
console.log(journalEvents(JOURNAL));
```

My question is how the if works in this function? especially (!), because when I remove this from the code, it returns an empty array? why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

[JOURNAL](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function journalEvents(journal) {
let events = [];
for (let entry of journal) {
  for (let event of entry.events) {
    if (!events.includes(event)) {
      events.push(event);
  }
 }
}
return events;
}


var JOURNAL = [
  {"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","nachos","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","nachos","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","brushed teeth","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","reading","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","ice cream","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","nachos","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","ice cream","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","peanuts","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":true},
  {"events":["potatoes","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","ice cream","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["peanuts","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","ice cream","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","ice cream","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","candy","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","nachos","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","beer","work","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","pudding","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","reading","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","pudding","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","peanuts","work"],"squirrel":true},
  {"events":["pizza","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","beer","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","peanuts","candy","work"],"squirrel":true},
  {"events":["carrot","peanuts","brushed teeth","reading","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","peanuts","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","peanuts","brushed teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","peanuts","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","candy","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["potatoes","nachos","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brussel sprouts","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["candy","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brussel sprouts","brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","candy","television","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","pudding","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","ice cream","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["spaghetti","peanuts","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":true},
  {"events":["bread","beer","computer","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","peanuts","brushed teeth","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","peanuts","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":true},
  {"events":["potatoes","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lasagna","ice cream","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","peanuts","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["cauliflower","peanuts","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false}
];


console.log(journalEvents(JOURNAL));
```

Steps how it process

1) when you pass the journal array , on the first for of loop it takes the first item which is `{"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},`

2) Then you have written another for of loop which will be taking the current entry.events which is an array `["carrot","exercise","weekend"]`

3) Then it starts iterating on the array , then comes the if loop, the condition you have written is something like , for example first it takes the first element of array which is `carrot`

4) so its like `[].includes("carrot")` which will return false , you can check [array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for detailed docs basically it will return whether the element is there or not in the array.

5) But the condition you have written is `![].includes("carrot")` which will be just opposite , which gives true

6) since the true satisfies your if conditon, it will enter into the if conditon which is to push the element to the events array.

7) Note: if you remove the `!` from the if conditon the if loop will be example

`[].includes("carrot")` so there is no carrot in the array so it gives false and doesn't enter to the if block, Thats why you need `!`, also for duplicate cases too.

The above cycle continues and the events array will not have any duplicate values

I hope you got it ..

Answer (score 2):

It works because `events.includes(event)` bassically check if event is in `(array) events.`
So, if the event is in the array `(!events.includes(event) - FALSE)`, it do nothing, but if the event isn't in `(array) events (!events.includes(event) - TRUE)` it make the `events.push(event)` - insert the event in the array.
That's why if you remove **!** and the array is empty, the IF will always go FALSE, because the array has no value to compare.